# Flutter list.builder not scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have in my body a tab then a column and in it I call to build a dynamic list of card using the another widget class. All seems to be working fine but I am getting this error.

```
The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 5090): A RenderFlex overflowed by 115 pixels on the bottom.
```

The issue is that the list is not able to scroll despite me wrapping it into a flexible widget. Here is the code snippet which builds the the list.I have also enable physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), yet the same issue. I know if I fix a particular height it will work but I dont want to to do that cause that defeats the whole idea.

```
Widget buildDynamicList(BuildContext context) {
    return new Flexible(
                //decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all(width: 2.0)),
                //height:double.infinity,

                //fit: FlexFit.loose ,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: vehicles.length,                      
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                        return Row( 
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, 
                          children: <Widget>[ 
                            RouteTile(index: index)
                         // expansionConfigurableRouteTile(ctxt, index), 
                          ], 
                          );
                      }
                     )    
          );         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexible only makes your child height variable. It does not make your lists scrollable. In order to do that, wrap your Flexible widget with a SingleChildScrollView widget.

Comment: I tried ready like this new Column(
                    
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SingleChildScrollView (child: 
                      buildDynamicList(context)
                      )
                      
                    ],
                  
     );

Comment: But it give me error Flexible widget must be placed directly inside a flex widget

Comment: @newbie Try it the other way around: put SingleChildScrollView on the outside of Flexible

Comment: I switch their placing the same old error on the A RenderFlex overflowed by 115 pixels on the bottom

Comment: what else could be the issue I know is just small tweak more I tried adding flex:1 still the same though

Comment: @newbie Hm... This is more complicated than I initially thought... Try the "Expanding content to fit the viewport" technique from https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Comment: @Timman it seems to be complicated. Let me try your suggestion

Comment: Hm... Not sure, then. Is the parent of the Flexible widget a Row or a Column, so that it knows which way to flex?

Comment: The parent is column

Answer (score -1):

removing `shrinkWrap: true` will do the trick

Comment: What does shrink wrap do is to enable it to save space right

Comment: yes without `shrinkWrap: true` list is not visible